# Simple for loop issue with arrays

Tags: java, arrays, loops

This is the code I have right now

```
for (int i = 0; i <= listOfPeople.length; i++){
    String name = scnr.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Person " + (i + 1) +  ": ");
    listOfPeople[i] = name;
}
```

List of people is a properly declared list of Strings with the length of a value the user sends in. The error that is happening is that when I run the program, I get this:

```
Person 1: 

Jordan

Person 2: 

Jordan

Person 3:

Jordan

Person 4: 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at RGG.main(RGG.java:20)
```

I am not quite sure what is wrong, but I have tried removing the = in the for loop declaration, then I get this output:

```
Person 1: 

Jordan

Person 2: 

Jordan

Person 3:
```

After the third prompt, the code moves on and I cant type in anything there. 
Does anyone know what might be happening? Thanks in advance!

Comment: As I said in the question, " I have tried removing the = in the for loop declaration", it still fails, see above issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `=` in this expression `i <= listOfPeople.length;`.  Its causing you to access an element of the array that does not exist.

```
for (int i = 0; i < listOfPeople.length; i++){
        String name = scnr.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Person " + (i) +  ": ");
        listOfPeople[i] = name;
}
```

Full Example:

```
public class PersonArrayTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] listOfPeople = new String[5];
        assign(listOfPeople);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(listOfPeople));
    }

    public static void assign(String[] listOfPeople) {

        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfPeople.length; i++) {
            String name = scnr.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Person " + (i) + ": ");
            listOfPeople[i] = name;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With this line

```
for (int i = 0; i <= listOfPeople.length; i++){
```

You are advancing one beyond the end of the array, length 3, which has valid indices 0-2.  3 is an invalid index.

When you remove the `=`, you get the corrected version:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listOfPeople.length; i++){
```

which stops after the `2` iteration, which is the end of the array, before you run off the end of the array.

Answer (score 1):

change this the `<=` sign in forloop

```
for (int i = 0; i < listOfPeople.length; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am make an educated guess that you are using `Scanner#nextInt` to get the input for the length of the array. Something along the lines of this:

```
String[] listOfPeople = new String[scnr.nextInt()];
```

I've garnered this because your loop code looks like this:

```
take input for i == 0
print prompt #1
take input for i == 1
print prompt #2
take input for i == 2
print prompt #3
```

But your output shows this:

```
print prompt #1
take input for i == 1
print prompt #2
take input for i == 2
print prompt #3
```

So what actually must be happening is this:

```
silently advance past whatever scnr is still retaining for i == 0
print prompt #1
take input for i == 1
print prompt #2
take input for i == 2
print prompt #3
```

`nextInt` orphans a new line character. (So will any calls to next_ besides nextLine.) That's why your first input is skipped. Calling `scnr.nextLine` in the first iteration of the loop just advances the Scanner past the last line.

Change the loop to this:

```
// skip the last new line
scnr.nextLine();

// < not <=
for (int i = 0; i < listOfPeople.length; i++) {

    // prompt before input
    System.out.println("Person " + (i + 1) +  ": ");

    // you don't need that extra String
    listOfPeople[i] = scnr.nextLine();
}
```